# Python - GUI - Tkinter listboxes

Tags: python, file, listbox, tkinter

i am having trouble loading one of my text files into my GUI. I have a load function(on the menubar), and have created a listbox.

The code for the loading the menu and the listbox:

```
class View(Listbox):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Listbox.__init__(self, master)      #makes view class listbox


class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Main interface:
        master - the top level window

        """
        self._master = master
        menubar = Menu(self._master)

        frame1 = Frame(self._master)
        frame1.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, padx=5,expand=True)

        self._Listbox=View(frame1)
        self._Listbox.pack(side = TOP,fill=BOTH, expand = True,pady=20)

        menubar = Menu(self._master)
        filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Open rooms file", command = self.file_open)


    def file_open(self):
        filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
```

The load file works, but where is the text document being currently loaded? How can i display it on my listbox?

Comment: sorry, i didn't type that properly. it was supposed to be display. Since i'm loading a text file into the GUI, i want the text file to be displayed onto the lixtbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFileDialog

class View(Listbox):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Listbox.__init__(self, master)      #makes view class listbox


class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Main interface:
        master - the top level window
        """
        self._master = master

        frame1 = Frame(self._master)
        frame1.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, padx=5,expand=True)

        self._Listbox=View(frame1)
        self._Listbox.pack(side = TOP,fill=BOTH, expand = True,pady=20)

        menubar = Menu(self._master)
        filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command = self.file_open)
        menubar.add_cascade(label='File',menu=filemenu)
        self._master.config(menu=menubar)

    def file_open(self):
        filename = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()

        #insert each line in the file into the listbox
        with open(filename,'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                self._Listbox.insert(END,line)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=Tk()
    c=Controller(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

This is only slightly different than your code...  First, I removed the first `menubar = Menu(self._master)` since it didn't really do anything.  Second, I added a "cascade" `menubar.add_cascade(label='File',menu=filemenu)`, third, I actually attached the menu to the root `Tk` window:  `self._master.config(menu=menubar)`

Comment: ? Sorry i didn't post my imports or my full code. But yes, this is what it looks like. Can you possibly make it so that when you load a text file, it will display it in the listbox?

Comment: I don't completely understand what you want ... the list box *is* displayed, there's just nothing in it.  What is in the text file?  Is each line of the text file supposed to be a new entry in the listbox?  Also, this isn't quite the same as your code -- I'll edit to point out the differences.

Comment: @AnthonyDo : I've edited to point out the differences between my code and yours -- I've also added a simple loop to pack each line in the file into a different line in the listbox.

Comment: Here is what i want, when i load the text document from the GUI. an image will be much better. http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/831/97707494.png/

Comment: thanks for that :). i'll have a play around with the file_open function  and see if i can get the format i want. i appreciate your time in helping me, thanks.